# From MySQL query to Elastic Search DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

*This question, though seems very lengthy but I have done a thorough research & reached to a working solution already but need some improvement with my solution.*

To start with, 
this is a `MySQL` Table named `content_table`:

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ id ║   title    ║   type   ║    genre    ║  countries  ║ devices ║ status ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ without me ║ playlist ║ rap         ║ US,AU,PK,NZ ║ 1,2,3,4 ║      1 ║
║  2 ║ Still Dre  ║ playlist ║ rap hits    ║ US,PK,NZ,AE ║ 1,4     ║      1 ║
║  3 ║ Scarface   ║ movies   ║ action      ║ US          ║ 4       ║      1 ║
║  4 ║ wild cats  ║ video    ║ documentary ║ UAE,PK,IN   ║ 1,2,5   ║      0 ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

I have indexed this table into **`Elastic Search cluster`** using the following settings & mapping.

```
{
   "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "filter":{
            "myNGramFilter":{
               "type":"edgeNGram",
               "min_gram":1,
               "max_gram":30
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{
            "myNGramAnalyzer":{
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"standard",
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase",
                  "myNGramFilter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{
      "content":{
         "properties":{
            "title":{
               "type":"text",
               "fielddata":true,
               "analyzer":"myNGramAnalyzer",
               "search_analyzer":"standard"
            },
            "countries":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "devices":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "genre":{
               "type":"text",
               "fielddata":true,
               "analyzer":"myNGramAnalyzer",
               "search_analyzer":"standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now I want to convert the following `MySQL` query into Query `DSL`

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  my_table 
WHERE status_srh <> 0,
  AND (
    countries IS NULL 
    OR FIND_IN_SET('US', countries_geo) > 0
  ) 
  AND FIND_IN_SET("1", device_ids) 
  AND (
    title LIKE "Still Dre" 
    OR genre LIKE "rap"
  ) 
  AND (
    TYPE <> 'playlist' 
    OR TYPE <> 'blocked content'
  ) 
GROUP BY id,
  type_srh 
ORDER BY title
```

So far, by following the the [Elastic Search Reference guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) this what I have ended up in order to convert **`MySQL query to Query DSL`** :

```
{
   "from":0,
   "size":100,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must_not":[
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "status":"0"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {"term": { "countries_geo": "US" }},
            {"term": {"device_ids": "2"}},
            {
               "bool":{
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "match_phrase":{
                           "title":"Still"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match_phrase":{
                           "genre":"rap"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must_not":[
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "type":"playlist"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "type":"blocked content"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":{
      "title":{
         "order":"asc"
      }
   }
}
```

This is so far working fine and returning me a result set without errors **BUT** my question here is that is there a way I can improve my approach and implement the same functionality more appropriately and efficiently.Any room for improvements ? An expert opinion would be very helpful for a beginner like me. Thankyou.

**UPDATE**
Added these two lines to the search DSL Query :

```
{"term": { "countries_geo": "US" }},
{"term": {"device_ids": "2"}},
```

Comment: Mapping does not show all the fields. Could not see mapping for `status` and `type`. could you please post updated mappings.

Comment: One way to improve your query is to get rid of the `regexp` queries. In order to achieve that you need to split your countries and devices into arrays of string.

Comment: How do you feed your ES index from MySQL?

Comment: @Richa I have not added mappings for status and type. Should I ?

Comment: @Val I am feeding ES using curl PUT calls to the ES API via a php script that fetches MySQL rows and feeds them to ES via the BULK API

Comment: In your PHP code, you should split the `countries_geo` and `device_ids` columns on commas, so that you store arrays of strings and integers into ES. That way you'll be able to get rid of the `regexp` queries.

Comment: @Danish yes please..

Comment: @Val using this reference : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html ?

Comment: @Val I have converted from comma seperated string to array and indexed it without providing any mapping for the two i.e countries_geo and device_ids. Now I am searching using the query under updated section (kindly see the question update) but I get no results. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Good. If you didn't specify any mapping, then your data gets stored as an analyzed string. You should be able to switch the a `match` query instead of a `term` one and it should work.